# Resend shipping email

Tags: orders, shipping

We had to print all shipping invoices but the email was at that time not sent. Now all orders are complete.

Is there a way to resend all the shipping emails en bulk?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
foreach (Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection() as $shipment) {
    $shipment->sendEmail(true);
}
```